# Framer motion first collapse animation is laggy (next js)

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

When the height is toggled for the first time it is laggy and then it becomes smooth

```
<AnimatePresence initial={true}>
    {isOpen && (
      <motion.div
        className={styles.content}
        key="content"
        initial="collapsed"
        animate="open"
        exit="collapsed"
        variants={{
          open: { opacity: 1, height: 'auto' },
          collapsed: { opacity: 0, height: 0 },
          exit: { opacity: 0, height: 0 },
        }}
      >
        {data.content}
      </motion.div>
    )}
  </AnimatePresence>
```